# Verb endings usage in DPRK

Tags: verb, north-korean

In the Korean language learning book, published in Pyongyang, the appendix shows Korean verb endings, including 네, 리라, 아라/어라/여라, 리, 마, which I met only in North Korean patriotic songs.

Are these endings used in the speech or TV/radio/press? Do these endings have specific use (like 아요/어요/여요, which is informal)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-네 is often used for poetic expression, but it is also used to express your confirmation of your feelings or the fact. For example, '오늘 날씨가 좋네.'
-리라,아라/어라/여라, 리 are same and are used in South Korea too. You could see them in the North Korea's patriotic songs easily because they're used in the situation to express your wishes. 
-마 is little different than above, as far as I know. You can use it when you tell somebody that you're gonna do something in the near or far future. The feeling of -마 is very informal and friendly. I saw them and heard them mostly in the letters of elders to their children.

Comment: Yeah, -리라 and -아라/어라/여라 are also commonly used in Korean-language hymns in churches in South Korea.

Comment: Does -마 have higher courtesy forms?